# getting many warnings for particular dags in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I just recently installed airflow and whenever I execute a task, I get warning about different dags:

```
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,691] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): create_entry_group>, delete_entry_group already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,691] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): delete_entry_group>, create_entry_group already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,691] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): create_entry_gcs>, delete_entry already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,692] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): delete_entry>, create_entry_gcs already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,692] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): create_tag>, delete_tag already registered for DAG:
 example_complex
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,692] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): delete_tag>, create_tag already registered for DAG:
 example_complex
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,759] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): prepare_email>, send_email already registered for DAG: example_dag_decorator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,759] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(EmailOperator): send_email>, prepare_email already registered for DAG: example_dag_decorator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,769] {example_kubernetes_executor.py:41} WARNING - The example_kubernetes_executor example DAG requires the kubernetes provider. Please install it with: pip install apache-***[cncf.kubernetes]
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,772] {example_local_kubernetes_executor.py:39} WARNING - Could not import DAGs in example_local_kubernetes_executor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d5291029/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_local_kubernetes_executor.py", line 37, in <module>
    from kubernetes.client import models as k8s
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,773] {example_local_kubernetes_executor.py:40} WARNING - Install Kubernetes dependencies with: pip install apache-***[cncf.kubernetes]
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,781] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,781] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,782] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,782] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,782] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,782] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,783] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2023-03-01 06:25:35,783] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
/home/d5291029/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py:159 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: Calling `DAG.create_dagrun()` without an explicit data interval is deprecated
```

How do i get rid of these warnings ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is known behavior for quite some time. There is a [GitHub Discussion thread](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/20693) about this if you'd like to follow along.

Unless you don't mix TaskFlow tasks and classic operators, this warning will continue to persist. It's somewhat intrusive, but it doesn't impact functionality.

Comment: Can I just delete the dags that are raising this warning to silent them? I tried airflow dags delete dag_id but it did not work for me